# How do i match a specific input within a string in Java?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I am using regex in this line of code:

```
if (line.matches("^.*\b(" + incomingMachineIP + ")\b.*$"))
```

So, assume the following inputs:

```
incomingMachineIp = "10.10.10.10"

line = "abcde=10.10.10.10abcedf"
```

I want the if condition to return true, which is what I'm trying to do with the regex above however a false is still returned even though the value of incomingMachineIp is found in the string (line)

Any help how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well obviously the first `.*` matches the whole string, so `incomingMachineIP` is not found afterwards.

Comment: Are you sure you want to return true when the incoming IP is `10.10.10.10`, but the line has `key=10.10.10.102`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash one more times and also you need to remove the second `\b` or replace with `\B` because there isn't a word boundary exists between the last `0` and the letter `a`

```
if(line.matches(".*\\b" + Pattern.quote(incomingMachineIP) + ".*"))
```

Since you're using matches method, it won't require anchors.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you can simply use `line.contains(incomingMachineIP)` and don't have to deal with regex patterns at all.

Answer (score 1):

use a live  [Regex Console](http://regex101.com) to test your expressions until you have got it working. Just remember to replace any single character backslash "\" with a double backslash character "\\" before using your expression in java!

Comment: Didn't know about that. I will find that extremely helpful for future use so thanks alot for that! :)